# is_open() is always returning 'false' when I try to read from a file

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I am trying to have a user input the name of a text file and read from it, but `is_open()` keeps returning `false`. I am compiling on my school's UNIX server, so a sample input would be `./a.out -f 4p.txt` where `4p.txt` is the name of the text file to be read from. My code is supposed to read this file from the `test_files` directory. I did it this way since I have 40+ different test files. Below is my code.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    string file = "4p.txt";
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1) //example input: ./a.out -f 3p.txt
        switch (c)
        {
        case 'f':
            file=optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'c')
                fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint (optopt))
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf (stderr,"Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",optopt);
            }
            return 1;
        default:
            abort ();
        }


    cout << "command line file input option example -f 1p.txt\ndefault is 4p\n";

    string fileopen="test_files/"+file;
    ifstream in(fileopen);
    if (!in.is_open())
        cout << "file failed to open\n";
}
```

The file that I intend to read from is in a folder titled `test_files` that is located in the same directory as my `.h` and `.cpp` files. For some reason, I keep getting a `file failed to open` prompt from my code, indicating that the file never opened.

Comment: Is "test_files" a subdirectory of the directory you ran the program in?

Comment: What does this print? `std::cout << get_current_dir_name();` Put it just before your open the file.

Comment: It works for me; no problems.

Comment: Yes, test_files is a subdirectory of the directory that the program is being ran in.

Comment: @AJNeufeld how are you compiling it? I'm using `g++ -std=c++11`.

Comment: @LokiAstari it prints the correct directory that the program is being run in

Comment: Is the case of the name correct?

Comment: Also can you print `std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` immediately after trying to open the file?

Comment: The the directory "test_files" must have read and execute permission and the file "test_files/<file>" must exist and have read permission.

Comment: It appears to be. I don't appear to be having problems with that when I singled it out.

Comment: @ColinLegge I build it with `make`.  Ok ... seriously, `c++ main.cc` and run as `./a.out`

Comment: I just checked the files. They all have read permissions allowed. They directory also has read and execute permissions allowed so that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: For clarity, I have `main.cc`, `a.out`, and `test_files` all in the same directory.

Comment: @Galik is says that `strerror was not declared in this scope` when I try to compile

Comment: @AJNeufeld I tried making the file and it still gives me the same problem. Not sure what the problem is. Could be something with my system if that's the case.

Comment: Add `cout << "fileopen = " << fileopen << "\n";` before you open the file.  And FYI, your program says the default is `4p`, but it is actually `4p.txt`.

Comment: `#include <cerrno> #include <cstring>` for `std::strerror(errno)`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld `fileopen` is shown to be `test_files/1p.txt` Immediately before attempting to open the file when I specify that I would like to read from `1p.txt`. So everything seems to functioning as desired except the ifstream.

Comment: And `ls -l test_files/1p.txt` gives you ...?  (grasping at straws here)

Comment: @Galik nothing is printed with strerror

Comment: Okay, guys, this is really embarassing, but I found the problem. The files that I was trying to read from were `.dat` file types. In the assignment description my teacher provided us, it says they are `.txt` files but the files she provided us were `.dat` files. I am sorry for this confusing. I have managed to get the program running. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well your code works for me. Did you remember to all the `-f` flag on the command line? Try: mkdir -p test_files; touch test_files/3p.txt; ./a.out -f 3p.txt`